# X axis tick marks and scale matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The below code works.

names: is the years 1960 - 2016

values: is the GDP of the US for each year

When you plot this the x axis has one tick for each year, making it unreadable.  Would like a tick for every five years, as an example.  How do I do this?  Can't seem to find a good example.

(system is not allowing me to upload the picture - not sure why)

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

# Plot GDP/Year

names =  usa.loc[: , "Year"]
values = usa.loc[: , "GDP Billions"]

plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 6))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(names, values)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(names, values)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like you are plotting strings instead of `datetime`s or numbers. This may in general lead to undesired plots if you expect your axis to be of numeric type instead of showing all categories you supply.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pyplot.xticks`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

# Plot GDP/Year

names =  usa.loc[: , "Year"]
values = usa.loc[: , "GDP Billions"]

plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 6))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(names, values)
plt.xticks(names[names % 5 == 0])

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(names, values)
plt.xticks(names[names % 5 == 0])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 57, step=5.0)) actually works.

Comment: 2020 update: "step=5.0" did not work for me but "minor =5.0" worked